# Converting vertical data to horizontal data + extracting first and last date

Tags: r, merge

I'm relatively new working with R. I have a database in which 2 columns look like the table below:

| pt_id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1222 | 20-01-2021 |
| 1222 | 18-11-2018 |
| 1222 | 17-02-2015 |
| 1222 | 21-04-2015 |
| 2555 | 18-01-2002 |
| 2555 | 03-04-2009 |
| 2555 | 25-12-2010 |

I would like to create a new dataframe in which `pt_id` are merged, and create 2 columns in which only the first date and the last date are saved. I would like it to look like a table below

| pt_id | Date_first | Date_last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1222 | 17-02-2015 | 20-01-2021 |
| 2555 | 18-01-2002 | 25-12-2010 |

The table above is just a small example, the database im working with is much larger.
These are the packages im working with at the moment:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(date)
library(reshape2)
library(foreign)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(irr)
library(vcd)
library(vctrs)
```

I hope this is possible, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that some of the packages you listed there get loaded when you run `library(tidyverse)` so there is some redundancy there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
mydf |>
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) |> # Only use if the variable is currently set to character
  group_by(pt_id) |>
  filter(Date == min(Date) | Date == max(Date)) |>
  mutate(date_vars = if_else(Date == min(Date), "Date_first", "Date_last")) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  pivot_wider(pt_id, values_from = Date, names_from = date_vars)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  pt_id Date_last  Date_first
  <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1  1222 2021-01-20 2015-02-17
2  2555 2010-12-25 2002-01-18
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for your answer! Sorry for this late reply, troubles in the working from home environment! I tried your script. Unfortunately it didnt work yet:  pat_id Date_first Date_last 
    <int> <list>     <list>    
 1 122894 <date [2]> <date [2]>
 2 336419 <date [2]> <date [2]>
 3 467840 <date [2]> <date [1]> Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

Comment: This means that there is other variables that you didn't mention that share the same characteristics, and therefore the pivoting function is unable to tell which value should go to which case. The simplest thing to do is create another unique by individual case, and then refer to that instead of  `pt_id` in the `pivot_wider()` function.

Comment: After some trial and error using your script it eventually worked out! Thank you very much Phil!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to R and thought I would have a go, to possibly inspire someone to correct me - this uses only base R and has a very convoluted for loop:

```
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date)
#Create a new df with a single entry for each patient
new_df <- unique(df1["pt_id"])

#make empty columns for the dates
new_df['date_first'] <- NA
new_df['date_last'] <- NA

#for each patient...
for (i in (1:nrow(new_df))){
  #make an empty list to store the list of dates...
  pt <- c()
  #and for each row in the original dataframe...
  for (j in (1:nrow(df1))){
    #make another empty list to store the single date for each record
    x = c()
    # and if the patient ID is in the row being read...
    if(df1[j,1]==new_df[i,1]){
      #append that date to list x and move on through the original df
      x<-append(x,df1[j,2])
    }
  #then append this list to the list pt...
  pt <- append(pt,x)
  }
#add the min and max values from the list pt to the new df for each entry in the new dataframe and move on to the next patient in the new dataframe
new_df[i,2] <- min(pt)
new_df[i,3] <- max(pt)
}

#make the columns dates again (as they were converted to numeric in the 
max/min)
new_df$date_first <- as.Date(new_df$date_first)
new_df$date_last <- as.Date(new_df$date_last)

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Hi HMCC, thank you for your answer. I tried your script. But the script takes a very long time to run and eventually stops most of the time. I think this is because the dataset might be too large (>200.000 pt_id's and >7million rows)